# How to grant IAM access to an already running EC2 intance

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-ami

## Background

I was handed over one AWS account at the root level by a business owner which runs different EC2 machines (staging/prod etc). What I want to do is simply create different IAM accounts that have restricted access. For example now I would like to create an IAM account that only has access to run, terminate a specific EC2 Instance.

## What I have tried

I basically followed instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html). I created an IAM group (called `superAdmin`), and I created a new IAM account and I assigned a new user (`user_1`) to that group.

Then I proceeded to create a [policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html), and attached it to the `superAdmin` group, the policy looks like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt15094*****",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:%my-account-id%:instance/i-%instance-id%"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I made sure the resource follows the [resource policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policy-structure.html#EC2_ARN_Format) to the dot. (note: the instances are running in Ireland, which according to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) is the same as `eu-west-1`)

I then called this policy `staging_access` and attached it to the `user_1` (but also removed all other policies):

[image]

## Problem

The problem is that when I login as `user_1`, I cannot see anything:

[image]

and when I go to the instances page, nothing shows:

[image]

## update

I noticed that if I simply made the resource a wild card.. everything would work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1509458879000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The interesting part is that even if I set the resource as a wild card on all ec2 like so:

```
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*"
        ]
```

it still doesn't work. Which means that accessing the console UI is a different [service namespace](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-ssm) than ec2.

Comment: ```I would like to create an IAM account that only has access to run, terminate a specific EC2 Instance``` do you mean stop/start existing EC2 or terminate/launch a new one?

Comment: @ALex_hha i want both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the policy based upon EC2 Instance ID. You need to add more permissions so that the user can display things like key pairs, volumes, instances, etc. There is a difference between assigning permissions to manage an EC2 instance from the command line, which can be very tight, versus the permissions needed to access the Amazon Management Console.

Also, your policy has % characters. Is this actually in your policy or is this just there to show in your question?

[Updated]

A better approach to controlling access to resources is to use Tags. For example to only allow user XYZ to access certain EC2 instances, tag the instances. Here is an example policy using tags. This policy allows the user to list all EC2 instances, but only allows all EC2 actions on instances tagged with their username.

```
{
     "Version" : "2012-10-17",
          "Statement" :
     [
          {
               "Effect" : "Allow",
               "Action" : "ec2:*",
               "Resource" : "*",
               "Condition" : {
                    "StringEquals" : {
                         "ec2:ResourceTag/UserName" : "${aws:username}"
                    }
               }
          },
          {
               "Effect" : "Allow",
               "Action" : "ec2:Describe*",
               "Resource" : "*"
          },
          {
               "Effect" : "Deny",
               "Action" :
                    [
                         "ec2:CreateTags",
                         "ec2:DeleteTags"
                    ],
               "Resource" : "*"
          }
     ]
}
```

Comment: in general the % character is to indicate a variable name.. naturally i won't show my actual instance id etc hehe

Comment: `You need to add more permissions so that the user can display things like key pairs, volumes, instances, etc. There is a difference between assigning permissions to manage an EC2 instance from the command line` so what will the permission json above look for all of those things? I'm more interested in console access rather than CLI access

Comment: see my update, it shows that what you're saying is incorrect

Comment: Just FYI sharing instance IDs is most likely safe. You can't even access them and it's your account. Knowing an instance ID doesn't give any access.

Comment: @abbood. What is incorrect in my answer?

Comment: I update my answer.

Comment: sorry didn't see that you updated it

Comment: Tip: Here is a CloudFormation template that uses Lambda to automatically tag EC2 type resources upon creation. This makes management of Owner tags very simple. Scroll down in this article for the template. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-tag-amazon-ec2-resources-in-response-to-api-events/

Answer (score 0):

## work around answer

This isn't really the answer i was looking for, but it serves my needs none the less. I created two policies and applied both to the same user

### policy 1: give them "spectator" access to everything:

Show Policy

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "***",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### policy 2: allow them to control a *specific* IAM

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "***",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:%account-id%:instance/i-%instance-id%"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```